# Rename a node in XML using xquery (basex)

Tags: xml, api, xquery, basex

This is the script that is run when the endpoint matches the `%rest:path`:

### XQuery

```
module namespace page = 'http://basex.org/examples/web-page';

import module namespace file = "http://expath.org/ns/file";

declare %updating
 %rest:path("/fnac")
 %rest:POST("{$body}")
 function page:fnac($body) {
   
 file:write("fnacData.xml",$body),
 db:create('prices', 'fnacData.xml', "./"),

 let $update := doc('C:\Users\franc\Desktop\basex\bin\fnacData.xml')
 for $n in $update//_
 return rename node $n as 'smartphone',

 update:output('Update Successful')
};
```

### XML

(The content of `$body`)

```
<json type="array">
  <_ type="object">
    <name>Samsung Galaxy S10+</name>
    <brand>Samsung</brand>
    <pageUrl>https://www.fnac.pt/Samsung-Galaxy-S10-G975FZ-128GB-Verde-Telemovel-SmartPhone-Android/a6587862</pageUrl>
    <price>1029.99</price>
    <details>G975FZ - 128GB - Verde</details>
    <imgUrl>https://static.fnac-static.com/multimedia/Images/PT/NR/ab/5c/4d/5069995/1545-1.jpg</imgUrl>
    <dateTime type="number">1579132283666</dateTime>
    <store>fnac</store>
  </_>
  <_ type="object">
    <name>Xiaomi Mi 9 Lite</name>
    <brand>Xiaomi</brand>
    <pageUrl>https://www.fnac.pt/Smartphone-Xiaomi-Mi-9-Lite-64GB-Black-Telemovel-SmartPhone-Android/a7166673</pageUrl>
    <price>339.99</price>
    <details>64GB - Black</details>
    <imgUrl>https://static.fnac-static.com/multimedia/Images/PT/NR/ca/73/55/5600202/1545-1.jpg</imgUrl>
    <dateTime type="number">1579132283667</dateTime>
    <store>fnac</store>
  </
</json>
```

The script is supposed to rename the node `<_>` to `<smartphone>` and update the XML file, but I can't make it work. It does return "*Update Successful*", however the XML file remains unchanged

Comment: In your query, you are creating a database for your document. Is there any particular reason for this additional step? Next, the file paths of the file:write and doc function calls differ. I guess you would like to address the same document here?

Comment: @Christian Grün I want to change the node's name, that's why I need that additional step. As for the file paths, I've tried using `doc("fnacData.xml")` but the results are the same. In the basex folder, this is the only document with the name "fnacData.xml" thus I believe it is addressing the same document

Comment: If you want to change node names in a local file, you can skip the database creation. If you want a document to be updated in a database, there's no need to use file:write. Maybe you need to specify more exactly what you want to do.